# Converting a while-loop with an array from Python to Assembly

Tags: python, assembly, avr

To prepare myself for the next school semester, I am trying to learn Assembly, a language I am not at all familiar with. I already know the basics of computer code and assembly coding and I have made a while-loop in Assembly before. However, this time I want to use an array.

I'm trying to convert a simple while-loop that I made in Python, to Assembly code but could use some assistance.

```
i = 2
numbers = []
while i <= 255:
    i -= 1
    numbers.append(i)
    i *= 3
    if i < 255:
        numbers.append(i)
    else:
        break
```

How can I do this? Once I have an idea of what it should look like, I can start studying the code and begin understanding it.

The computer architecture I'm using is an AVR ATMEGA328P

This is a for-loop I made earlier. It's pretty random and probably not very efficient, I was just practicing:

```
loop:
      cpi r16,255
      breq notthree
      mov r18, r16
      cpi r17,6
      brne notsix
      sub r17,r16
      rjmp loop
notthree:
      cpi r17,3
      breq notthree
notthree:
      dec r16
      rjmp loop
end_loop:
```

Comment: This is a broad question. You don't even mention the computer architecture.

Comment: Whoops! fixed it

Comment: Show what you did. If you already made a while-loop you should be able to start. PS: note that in assembly you don't typically want to dynamically grow an array, you will probably need an array preallocated to some maximum length and possibly use a variable to show the number of items used.

Comment: Added it @Jester !

Comment: You should probably familiarize with the limitations of low level languages by trying to write this kind of stuff in C or something like that - you'll understand that lots of stuff that you may take for granted in Python - strings, dynamically-sized data structures - take a lot of effort, and you typically avoid some of them altogether if not strictly necessary, or learn how to implement them from scratch if you actually need them. A fully dynamically sized array as you used typically needs three pointers and some heap manager, but in C or in assembly generally you'll use a static buffer.

Comment: That's to say that it's difficult to provide you with a perfect translation of your code, because it would require some allocator (which is not provided if you are coding "on the bare metal") and quite some code, and the final result wouldn't resemble what you would actually write in assembly to achieve that result. Given that your algorithm requires less than 256 elements in the array (and all of them smaller than 256), I would allocate 256 bytes either of static storage, or on the stack, and keep a pointer/index to the next one to use. On x86 straight using the stack may also be an option.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: oh right, an allocator.  That's probably why AVR gcc on Godbolt doesn't have `#include <vector>`.  In case anyone's wondering what a transliteration of that python code into C++ with `std::vector<int>` looks like, I put it up on https://godbolt.org/g/dmFf1y.  ARM32 asm it a RISC ISA that's not totally dis-similar to AVR, but it does use predicated instructions instead of branches for some things (including a predicated store).  Anyway, the asm output is pretty unreasonably huge since it has to check for needing to resize the vector on every `push_back` / `emplace_back`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm not sure, if the AVR toolchain Godbolt provides similar to the usual Arduino one it should have `malloc` (although I've always been curious about how can you use it effectively on a micro with 2 KB of total RAM) - but it's true that even on the Arduino toolchain the STL is not provided.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: *very* few C library functions return dynamically allocated storage.  Other than `malloc` itself, there are GNU extensions like `strdup` and `asprintf`.  I'm not surprised there's no C++ STL (or whatever it's properly called these days) for AVR, since using it usually bloats the code too much. (like that godbolt example shows!)  Thanks for confirming that it's not just a Godbolt limitation.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yeah, what I meant in fact was: why bother at all providing `malloc`, in such a constrained environment you cannot afford trying not to think about how much you allocate, so using a statically sized buffers is pretty much the only way to go; providing a `malloc` is just wasting flash space. OTOH some of the STL *can* be used - `std::array` and STL algorithms have no runtime cost and can provide useful facilities pretty much for free - but I'm digressing.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: yeah, it seems weird.  Any idea what the `malloc` implementation is like?  Or if it's just a prototype and you have to provide an implementation yourself?  Or is it just implemented as `return NULL;`, which the C standard may technically allow :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: no no, it's provided, several Arduino libraries do use it. I read just now [how it's implemented and it's pretty clever](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html), it needs overall two bytes to track the end of the heap and two bytes per active allocation, it has a simple block search algorithm and automatic adjacent free blocks coalescing; also, I'd say it is mostly thought for micros with larger, external RAM available - again, with 2 KBs of total RAM using dynamic memory is really a gamble.

Answer (score 0):

this question is pretty far beyond the scope we can usually answer in a question. Python is a very high-level language, so a good place to begin may be by learning some C, especially regarding pointers. C is basically the layer above a computer's own language. It allows programs be written in a more cross-platform way.

Things like arrays and references don't behave the way that their higher level counterparts, lists and variables do. The idea behind an array is to store a contiguous region of data. In very simple implementations, they are stored using an address pointer and indexed by performing math on that pointer to find nearby addresses. In bounds-checked implementations, either a `NULL` terminator value or a header indicating the size can be used to prevent reading data outside of the array.

The layer between high-level languages and low-level languages is often much harder to study than the languages themselves, because it requires understanding the design of both parts in order to appreciate their connection. With a simple google search, you can find various `asm` tutorials, such as [How to make an assembly array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm). Note that `asm` is the broad term for a family of interconnected languages that are unique to their architectures.

Good luck on your journey, and feel free to ask broad questions such as this in chatrooms (such as our [HCF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98738/halt-and-catch-fire-assembly)), ircs, or discord servers. When anything specific causes you trouble, come write up a question here.